# Transformation Function

Tags: calculus

How can I proof that if I apply a transformation that is always strictly increasing the properties of the Hessian remains the same to the new transformation.\ My Initial Hessian is
$$Hf(x)\equiv \begin{bmatrix} D_{1,1}f(p) &D_{1,2}f(p) \\ D_{2,1}f(p)& D_{2,2}f(p) \end{bmatrix}\equiv \begin{bmatrix} r & s \\ r & t \end{bmatrix}$$
And this are my properties $$ rt-s^2 >0 \ \ r>0$$
Will this properties be the same for the new transformation. How can I proof it?